# Тестирование ПО, автоматизация получения Code Coverage LCOV

Tags: c++, netbeans, jenkins, непрерывная-интеграция, codecoverage

Поставил перед собой задачу в автоматизации прогона тестов при коммите (для реализации данного функционала юзаю Jenkins). Вроде бы всё хорошо, тесты прогоняются и видно OK/KО. Однако, мне недостаточно этого для определения структурного покрытия кода. Поискав методики получения покрытия я остановился на LCOV+henhtml. В принципе удобный, фришный инструмент. Однако, мне пока немного непонятно, как автоматизировать выполнение команды LCOV? Собственно, имею несколько вопросов:

1. Каким образом мне автоматизировать выполнение lcov+genhtml? Ведь эти команды выполняются в msys, а я работаю в OS Windows. Возможно, мне стоит каким то образом модифицировать MakeFile?
2. Могу ли я как графически отобразить покрытие кода в Jenkins? Присутствует для этого какой либо плагин?
3. Возможно существует какой-то более удобный инструмент (фришный) для сбора покрытия?

Используемое ПО

- NetBeans IDE 8.2
- ```
  COLLECT_GCC=g++
  COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/lto-wrapper.exe  
  Target: mingw32  
  Thread model: win32  
  gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)
  ```
- OS Win7
- CppUnit
- Jenkins (Запущен на устройстве под OS Win7)

Comment: Отформатировал немного код, чтобы лучше читался. Смысл же не нарушился?

Comment: TeamСity в этом плане, конечно, рулит

Comment: а вы не рассматривали другие инструменты для покрытия, gcov, например?  она вроде легко интегрируется с CI. еще вот эту http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/Jenkins-Cpp-builds.html статью посмотрите, пожалуйста. там уже есть несколько ответов

Comment: Senior Automator, gcov предоставит мне инфу в текстовом виде. Это сложнее воспринимается. Меня интересует Lcov, поскольку его выхлоп более понятен (сугубо на мой взгляд).

Comment: Не должен. Ну это не совсем код, а часть выхлопа gcc -v в консоли.